# Why is my screen black when I do VNC from my phone to my laptop and how can I fix it?

Tags: vnc

Why is my screen black when I do VNC from my phone to my laptop and how can I fix it?

Hello,

I am connecting from my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) to my laptop running Linux Ubuntu 15.10 over VNC using a D-link router connected to the Ethernet port of the laptop.

The screen as shown on my mobile phone is black. I can move the finger on the mobile screen and the mouse pointer will move correspondingly on the laptop so there has to be some kind of connection but I cannot see anything because the mobile screen is black.

How can I fix this?

Vesa

Android app: bVNC

Comment: Did you try a different app e.g. `VNC Viewer`? You could also try a different VNC server on your Ubuntu machine like [VNC connect](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/linux/)

Comment: Hi @spiderpig. The combination vino-server on the laptop and bvnc viewer app on Android has been working well for a long time. Just recently it doesn't work any more. Update, now the screen is not black anymore, the mobile phone screen actually reflects the laptop screen but it's frozen. So I can see the ubuntu screen on the mobile phone but when I move the mouse around and do stuff it only happens on the laptop screen. So the android screen is static. I don't know what has happened and I need this to work. Today I tried to install a bunch of other vnc software but none of them seemed to start